# actionscript scrolling

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

In AS3 I am trying to have my background scroll horizontally when the mouse is on the right side of the stage. (My background instance is called "bp".)

This isn't working:

```
while (mouseX > 600)
  {bp.x -= 2;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash user interface is updated frame-by-frame, and should not be blocking such as your while loop implementation.

Every frame, you can test mouseX position and determine how much to scroll your background.

Here's an example implementation:

```
import flash.events.Event;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHandler);

function frameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var d:Number = (stage.stageWidth >> 1) - stage.mouseX;
    bg.x -= d * 0.1;
}
```

Comment: This is correct. As further clarification, the `while` loop is run just once. It is not constantly run, checking `mouseX > 600`. It runs it once, determines it's false, and moves on. The way the loop is currently set up, it would never run again. Follow what Jason has laid out and you'll get this to work. Alternatively, you could also do it in a MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE handler. That would likely be a little less CPU intensive on your single thread application.